# Connecting Apache Drill to Kudu

Tags: apache-drill, apache-kudu

Is there a way to connect Apache Drill to Kudu?

I have seen Drill 1.5 added an experimental support for Kudu and a drill-storage-kudu on github but I can't figure out how to make it work... Is this now less experimental?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to drill Web UI and click on **storage**

Update Kudu plugin with your appropriate Kudu master address.

```
{
  "type": "kudu",
  "masterAddresses": "1.2.3.4",
  "enabled": true
}
```

If it's updated successfully, you will be able to query on Kudu Tables via Drill.

***P.S.** I have not used this functionality so can't comment on it's experimental status.*

Comment: Thank you but where do i install the plugin ?

There is no kudu there. It is said to be added in 1.5 but i don't see it in the "storage" tab.

I've seen a "drill-storage-kudu" on github so i imagine it's possible to add it but i don't know how.

Comment: create a new plugin with name **kudu** or whatever you want and copy plugin details into `Configuration` and click on create.

Comment: That's all ? No driver or code ? Ok. I'll try this.

Comment: @Jice Kudu client jar is already added in `apache-drill-1.5.0/jars/3rdparty` directory. There should be `drill-kudu-storage-1.5.0.jar` in `apache-drill-1.5.0/jars` directory.

Comment: In Drill 1.5 & 1.6,  it's using `kudu-client-0.6.0.jar`. Currently kudu has 1.2 version. In newer version, they might have used latest driver.

Comment: OK Thanks for your complete answer and patience. I'll try this (this evening). I begin to understand :-).

Comment: It's ok now. I used drill in a docker container and the image was too old. Thanks for your help.